# Selecting external data source in DMX

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, dmx-ssas

Using `Microsoft SSAS` and `SQLServer 2012` I am currently trying to update my `timeseries` model by using new values from my original source database table.

The Microsoft tutorials present for `DMX` suggesting using `EXTEND_MODEL_CASES` to update the model using `PREDICTION JOIN` and static values, for the sake of automation my aim is to do this using a `SELECT FROM` but am unsure how to refer back to my original data source.

**EDIT : CLARIFICATION:** *the below code does not work as SSAS cannot seem to access my database table this way* **The question** therefor is: How can I select a database table from within SSAS

```
 SELECT [DumpLocation_Id],
 PredictTimeSeries([TotalDumpCount],5, EXTEND_MODEL_CASES) AS PredictDmpCnt
 FROM
 [DumpForecasting_MIXED]
 NATURAL PREDICTION JOIN 
 ( select * from DumpStatistics3
  where TimeIndex >= (getdate() - 2))
 AS t
```

**My expectation** is to get a result set from said table inserted into my model.

Say my model contains:

```
 DumpLocation_id     |  TimeIndex   |   TotalDumpCount  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
  1                  |01-01-2014    |   23
  1                  |02-01-2014    |   13
  1                  |03-01-2014    |   14
```

I want to be able to select the data from my Database Table:

```
  DumpLocation_id     |  TimeIndex   |   TotalDumpCount  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
  1                  |01-01-2014    |   23
  1                  |02-01-2014    |   13
  1                  |03-01-2014    |   14    
  1                  |04-01-2014    |   15
  1                  |05-01-2014    |   17
```

and add it to my model so that the newer entries get entered into my model.

Comment: What is the question? (looks more like `tSQL` rather than `MDX`)

Comment: @whytheq Actually, it is **DMX**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132031.aspx. But there does not seem to be a tag for DMX on SE, at least not the DMX language of SSAS.

Comment: @FrankPl I've attempted to create a tag - needs a description though. I know nothing about it so will leave that to you. Think once you get into 10000+ territory Frank you get extra tag privileges (wow!).

Comment: Even though I find`Microsoft ASS`slightly funny, you should probably change it to`Microsoft SSAS`and`ASS`->`SSAS` :)

Comment: Analysis Service Server(ASS) seemed just fine to me :p but I see your point.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what it is exactly that I'm hoping to achieve. I really hope someone can help me out on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to place what I came up with on here in case someone else runs into the same problem:

In order to select Tables from a relationalDatabase `DMX` supports the `OPENQUERY` statement (this has also been implemented in `tsql`)

`OPENQUERY` takes a string as argument that holds an equivalent of a `tsql` query.

example:

```
OPENQUERY (relDatabaseServer, 'SELECT name FROM example.titles WHERE name = ''NewTitle''');
```